# Pass a variable from an action to another action's view in ZF

Tags: php, zend-framework, variable-assignment

I want to know that does zend allow this thing and if yes than how?

```
public xAction()
{
// code here
}

public yAction(){
 $this->_helper->viewRenderer('x');
// code here....
// $this->view->variable= $somedata;
}

**x.phtml**

<?php echo $this->variable; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend allows the rendering of a different view script. 
You can do it like this: `$this->_helper->viewRenderer('controller/action', null, true);`
[More info here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.viewrenderer) (Example #11)

Comment: in which action I have to write this?

Comment: In your case the y action. Something like `$this->_helper->viewRenderer('x');`

Comment: I already did this I want to access `$this->view->variable= $somedata;` in x.phtml

Comment: It should be accessible if you set it in the current(`y` in your case) action.

Comment: The variables used in the view script should be set in the action rendering the view.

Comment: mean I should set the variable first in yAction than pass it to xAction and than access it.....?

Comment: You should set the var in the `*Action`(x,y or other) function that is using the .phtml file as a view script.

Comment: thanks.... for solving the problem.... I got the solution... from your last comment.....